# Loop through array with html forms

Tags: php, forms

I want to loop through an array of names within my form and check the a property, `is_verified` for a given ID.

**form:**

```
<div class="input">
    <?php echo form_dropdown(
        "is_email_verified[{$email->id}]", [
            0 => 'no',
            1 => 'yes'
        ], $email->is_verified, 'id="is_'. $email->id . '_verified"'
    ); ?>
</div>
```

**print_r($this->input->post()) gives:**

```
"Array ( 
     ...
     [is_email_verified] => Array(
           [123] => 1
      )
```

Let's say there are more than one e-mails, and I'm looping through these e-mails, checking if the id's (in this case, 123) `is_verified` bool is set to 0 or 1.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
foreach ($member->emails as $email) {
   if ($this->input->post("is_email_verified[$email->id]") == '1') {
```

How can I loop through the form values and check against that specific ID in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the array from the post data, then access the array via the desired index.

```
foreach ($member->emails as $email) {
    if ($this->input->post("is_email_verified")[$email->id] == '1') {
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to extract your code a little bit and change it like this. This way it might be easier to debug.

```
foreach ($member->emails as $email) {

    $postArray = $this->input->post();
    $emails = $postArray['is_email_verified'];
    $verified = $emails[$email->id];

    if($verified == 1) {

    }
}
```